# Bootstrap carousel news slides timing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've been developing a wordpress template with a bootstrap (3.3.6.) carousel news slider. But the slides timing is all wrong after a few seconds. I already set a timer in custom.js, but it only worked on the news button (replacement of indicator), while the slides are moving way too fast after a few seconds.The weirdest thing is, if I change the bootstrap link to the cdn, the slides move properly but the news button are not moving at all. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is the website for you to review: http://tfcakalimantan.org

The front-page.php

```
        <?php

      $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'tag'               => 'featured',
        'posts_per_page'    => 5 
      );
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="list-group col-sm-4" style="padding-right: 0px;"> <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $the_query->current_post; ?>" class="list-group-item <?php if( $the_query->current_post == 0) echo 'active'; ?>"><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5></li><?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </ol>
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>


      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
             <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>  
             <?php
                $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
                $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
                $thumbnail_meta = get_post_meta( $thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);                
              ?>   
        <div class="item <?php if( $the_query->current_post == 0) echo 'active'; ?>">

          <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url[0]; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $thumbnail_meta; ?>">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

          </div></div>
          <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div><!-- End Item -->


      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
</div>
 <!-- Controls -->
 <div class="row">
      <div class="carousel-controls">
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
      </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
```

The custom.js

```
// Carousel

$(document).ready(function(){
    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 2000  
    }).on('click', '.list-group li', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.list-group li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');     
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.list-group').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.list-group li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.list-group li').first().addClass('active'); 
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});

$(window).load(function() {
    var boxheight = $('#myCarousel .carousel-inner').innerHeight();
    var itemlength = $('#myCarousel .item').length;
    var triggerheight = Math.round(boxheight/itemlength+1);
    $('#myCarousel .list-group-item').outerHeight(triggerheight);
});
```

The style.css

```
    /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */
#myCarousel .carousel-caption {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    text-shadow:none;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#myCarousel .list-group {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
}
#myCarousel .list-group-item {
    border-radius:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#myCarousel .list-group .active {
    background-color:#6D9755;   
}

#myCarousel .item {
    height: 300px;  
}
.carousel-controls {display:none;}
```

Comment: Well, is there anyone that can help?

Comment: 17 days have passed and I'm still stuck.